# Using JavaScript Validator to invalidate email domains

Tags: javascript, validation, email, dns

I have a page with a form. It uses the validator found at http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/form-validation.phtml to validate the input (including the users email address).

Problem:

I need to exclude emails from a list of domains. How can I perform this using the form validation library?

Comment: you'll need to learn javascript, its easy enough to learn. But what you would prob need to do is to create a array of domains to exclude and then use something like `domain= email.replace(/.*@/, "");` to get the domain of the email submitted and use indexOf to find the domain in the array. Of course if its to prevent spam, it will be a long list and users can just change the email used to submit

Comment: Brendan, thanks for the direction. Yea, learning JS is on my 'to-do' list. But it seems I'm spending so much time just trying to keep from drowning that I don't have time to learn how to swim. Metaphorically speaking. :(

And yes, the length of the list could be rather long. My initial instructions were to just use the big three (Gmail, Yahoo and MSN/Hotmail/Live). But I know from experience that if they start getting submissions from other free services they are gonna want them all added. Then it'll get really ugly.

Thanks again for the response.